An item with with the same key has already been added
I am following a tutorial of model-first approach in ASP.NET MVC in which I am using ADO.NET Entity Model Data, empty EF designer model and when generating the database after defining it's properties getting an error

An Item with the same key has already been added

Here's my model:
My Model
And this is a error I get:
Couldn't generate DDL, Error
I tried rebuilding the solution and making sure that the model doesn't have duplicate keys.
Update - Just tried the same in a different folder and it worked.

Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images. They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Also, show the code that actually throws the exception.

@GertArnold Thank you for taking the time to guide me. I apologise for posing my inquiry in this way, I fully understand why it is not recommended. I had to include pictures because there was no code involved and it was related to UI. Thanks

The model you show does have generated code in a generated C# class. We don't see the data types, for example, that are visible in the class definition. The entity you show doesn't look like anything that could cause trouble. Apart from what's said so far: I'd strongly recommend to not go this path anyway. EDMX is deprecated, soon rather than later there won't be any support for it in newer Visual Studio versions. If you want to learn EF and ASP.Net MVC, watch newer tutorials using .net 6 minimums.

@GertArnold Okay, thank you.
